# Archived emails still taking up space in Outlook

Tags: outlook.com, email

I am having some problem with the archive option in Outlook. My mailbox is almost full and I am archiving all the emails which are one year old. But, archiving is also taking up space.

Do you know what could be the issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could try emailing yourself a 50 Mb attachment from another account.  Once it comes in, archive it and see how much space it takes.  It's likely that archiving keeps attachments at their original size.

Answer (score 0):

Export your mail to file and then delete archived mail. Archiving mail is not the same as deleting, it only means to move mail from your main inbox.

Edit: I am not sure about web app, but for example if you use Outlook for desktop you will find theese options under file - export / import